# Create 2 RSS Readers in Xcode

Tags: ios, rss

I have created an RSS reader that first displays the articles in a Table View and then if you click to an article you go to a View Controller that it has a WebView Controller to display the website of that article. The App is based of a Tab Bar Application and I would like to created another Tab with a different RSS URL. How can I do it?

Here is the beginning of my TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController () {
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSString *element;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
feeds= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MYRSSFEEDURL"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
}
```

This is how it should look like:
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/3896/WY3jxC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drag new UIViewController of the type you wish to your storyboard
2. Drag `Tab Bar Item` to the bottom of your new UIViewController
3. Right click on your `Tab Bar Controller` and drag to the newly created UIViewController
4. From the options select `Relationship Segue - ViewControllers`
5. Create class from new ViewController and register it in Storyboard

Comment: I have done that and when I try to do the same code for the second RSS reader I get this error: ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Comment: Should I change the name I put to the elements?

Comment: Am I correct, that you registered the same class for the new ViewController as for previous one?

Comment: No, I didn't. I created new files and I assign a the class of this new files to the second View Controller but the code used in the new files that I created is the same one used in the original files just changing the url of the RSS and of course in the file s what I import in the beginning of the code is also different but I get that error.

Comment: I've just created app by instructions I've mentioned above and it successfully compiled and run. So, I can't reproduce the error and it does not say anything to me, because there might be more than one cause for it. I may guess that you could make a mistake when were copying files from one class to another and e.g. forgot to change #import directives.

Comment: I get this error: ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)